# mysql—how to add custom ids without messing up auto-increment?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

My work has multiple clones of the same database structure (same structure, but different sets of data). Each clone is called a pod.

Recently we have started moving sets of data from one pod to a new one. This is raising all kinds of chaos because we are bringing the ids from the old database into the new one, and multiple records are having the same ids.

*Disclaimer—I am super against the entire premise of what's happening, but decisions have been made and I need to make it work.*

I had a thought that as we are migrating the data, we could just add a prefix like `old_id * 1000` to the ids, to blow it way past the current auto-increment counter.

- **Is there a way to do this without changing the counter?** (otherwise doing this a couple times will set the counter to numbers outside int limits).
- Also, **when the counter reaches these numbers, will it simply skip over existing ids** and go to the next free slot? Or will there be nasty collisions?

Comment: Your idea will have most likely give collisions in the future.. Sounds like using UUID/GUID in this case is more usefull then a auto_increment

Comment: But as UUID/GUID shatters performance as the string is more random vs a auto_increment, you have to use tricks.. @RickJames has a [trick](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) on his website http://mysql.rjweb.org/

Comment: .... besides that there is no good other solution..

Comment: The old ID is not an ID anymore: you killed it. You need to add another field as true ID, that can be auto_increment or can be calculated in some way from the old ID, at your discretion. (I see this all the time on my company databases. I'm with you...)